# Need to assign average data of array element to ng-model : Angular

Tags: angularjs, arrays, average, angular-ngmodel

I received JSON Object, in which there's one array element, I want average of those numeric data and assign it to ng-model in view.

my Json object.

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": [{
        "name": "[1] Data 1",
        "ratings": [4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 5, 3]
    }, {
        "name": "[2] Data 2",
        "ratings": [2, 4, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5]
    }, {
        "name": "[3] Data 3",
        "ratings": [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
    }]
}
```

Now in view, I want to assign average of 'ratings' data to uib-rating's ng-model

My View

```
  <ul class="video-list">
        <li ng-repeat="data in getVideoListsCtrl.result" class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12" ng-click="getVideoListsCtrl.loadSingleVideoAndPlay(data)">
          <span class="vname">{{data.name}}</span>
          <span class="vratings">
            <span uib-rating ng-model={{data.ratings | avarageConverter}} max="max" read-only="isReadonly">
            </span>
          </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

I tried using calling function or applying filter.

```
.filter('avarageConverter', function() {
    return function (arr) {
      var sum = 0;
      for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
      }
      return sum / (arr.length === 0 ? 1 : arr.length);
    };
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new property to your JSON object that stores the average and then assign that to your `ng-model`. Once you retrieve the data in your controller, you could loop through the `data[]` and add a new `average` property which is the average rating for the item and in your view bind this your `ng-model`:

`<span uib-rating ng-model="data.average" max="max" read-only="isReadonly"></span>`

Answer (score 0):

Create a DTO in the server side that have the attributes: name, ratings and average. Calculate the average in the server side (your rest api) and return it in the DTO.